# How to select minimum values for duplicate ids using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can someone please help me on this.

I have data like this

```
**id,age,name**
10,25,abc
10,35,def
20,45,ghi
20,55,jkl
20,65,mno
30,40,pqr
30,50,stu
30,70,vwr
40,20,yza
40,25,fdf
40,25,dgh
40,20,sfs
```

Now I want to get the final result as below

```
+------+------+
| id   | age  |
+------+------+
|   10 |   25 |
|   20 |   45 |
|   30 |   40 |
|   40 |   20 |
|   40 |   20 |
+------+------+
```

I am able to do this in mysql but as hive do not support multiple arguments in sub query so I am not able to get desired result in hive.

I tried doing this using hive join but no success.

Thanks in advance for help!!

Comment: Din't this query select id,min(age) from tr group by id; work ? What error are you getting ? What have you tried in Hive ?

Comment: No, This didn't work.query  "select id,age from test1 where (id,age) in (select distinct(id), min(age) from test1 group by id)" work well in mysql but it is giving syntax error in hive bcz two columns are not supported in IN clause.

Comment: I think this is only possible with hive join but I am not able to figure out, how to do.

Comment: (1) What are the header columns of the data? (2) What is the connection between the data and the final results?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I have updated my question with headers.I just got this data and output from one of my client.

Comment: What is the transformation logic? Why would id 10 returned with age 25? Why would id 40 returned twice?

Comment: Your Input table and expected output is not mached wih your description "How to select minimum values for duplicate ids using hive". according to your description: ID 10 should return age value 20 not 25

Comment: By mistake previously I posted wrong data.Accept my apologies.I have updated the question now. @DuduMarkovitz

Answer (score 0):

Other way to implement expected output.

```
SELECT id,
       age
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          age
   FROM tblname) a LEFT SEMI
JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          MIN(age) age
   FROM tblName
   GROUP BY id) b ON a.id=b.id
AND a.age=b.age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  id
       ,age

from   (select  id
               ,age

               ,rank () over 
                (
                    partition by    id 
                    order by        age
                ) as rnk

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   t.rnk = 1
```

---

```
+----+-----+
| id | age |
+----+-----+
| 10 |  25 |
| 20 |  45 |
| 30 |  40 |
| 40 |  20 |
| 40 |  20 |
+----+-----+
```

Comment: yes, this is more accurate..Can we acchive same with left semi join and join on both id and age..

Comment: @ManishSarafBhardwaj - What would be the motivation for that?

Comment: just to curios and improve knowledge on different implementations. thats it.